# My object isn't displaying when i use the javascript constructor method to create an object

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CREATE JAVASCRIPT OBJECTS USING OBJECT-LITERAL</h1>
    <P id="text"></P>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        document.write("OBJECT CREATION");

        function char(name, anime, specie){
            this.name = name;
            this.anime = anime;
            this.specie = specie;
        }
        var character = char("Goku", "dragonballz", "saiyan");
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = character.name + " is from " + character.anime + " and he is a super " + character.specie + " Alien ";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So... As you can see, I tried using the javascript constructor method to create an object, And its not dispaying, In the console it said character which is the variable name is undefined.
I'm just currently learning javascript, so i would love to get some help.

Comment: [Constructor documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Constructor#syntax).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `new` keyword to create an object instance from the constructor function.

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>CREATE JAVASCRIPT OBJECTS USING OBJECT-LITERAL</h1>
    <P id="text"></P>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        document.write("OBJECT CREATION");

        function char(name, anime, specie){
            this.name = name;
            this.anime = anime;
            this.specie = specie;
        }
        var character = new char("Goku", "dragonballz", "saiyan");
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = character.name + " is from " + character.anime + " and he is a super " + character.specie + " Alien ";
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

For more resources.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new